# Does http server use different port for listening and further communication

Tags: java, networking

As I have read HTTP server listen on port 80 . But in case we have multiple connection from different client , in that case does HTTP server use dynamic ephemeral ports to communicate and keeping port 80 free for taking incoming connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right it does listen on port 80 for HTTP even though it could be any port technically speaking.

If you have multiple connections from different clients, what will happen from client side? Each TCP connection will have a random source port and a destination port of 80. Destination IP will be the HTTP server IP and src IP is the client src IP.
How will the HTTP server responds? Simply by reversing the src/dst IP and ports.

So if you have an incoming connection from 151.X.Y.Z:57845 --> 145.X.Y.Z:80, the response will be to 145.X.Y.Z:80 --> 151.X.Y.Z:57845

You have to understand that having multiple src port of 80 is not an issue. A TCP socket is based on src port, dst port, src ip, dst ip. Those are multiple variables not just one.